# Firebase Functions times out when using puppeteer's browser.newPage()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have seen others having relatively minor performance problems with puppeteer running on Firebase Functions. In my case, Firebase times out before I can do *anything* with puppeteer, even with the memory and timeoutSeconds cranked all the way up.

Code:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const runScreenshot = async () => {
  console.log("Launching puppeteer...");
  console.time("launch");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  console.timeEnd("launch");

  console.log("Awaiting browser.newPage()...");
  console.time("newPage");
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.timeEnd("newPage");

  console.log("Setting viewport...");
  console.time("setViewport");
  page.setViewport({ width: 2000, height: 4000, deviceScaleFactor: 4 });
  console.timeEnd("setViewport");

  console.log("Goto page...");
  console.time("goto");
  await page.goto(
    "https://public.tableau.com/views/NCDHHS_COVID-19_Dashboard_Summary/NCDHHS_DASHBOARD_SUMMARY"
  );
  console.timeEnd("goto");

  console.log("Waiting for selector...");
  console.time("selector");
  await page.waitForSelector("#tab-dashboard-region");
  console.timeEnd("selector");

  // Wait for the spinner to go away
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 100));

  console.time("href");
  const href = await page.$("#tab-dashboard-region");
  console.timeEnd("href");

  console.time("screenshot");
  href && (await href.screenshot({ path: "tmp/test.png" }));
  console.timeEnd("screenshot");

  return browser.close();
};

export const screenshot = functions
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.schedule("44 21 * * *")
  .timeZone("America/New_York")
  .onRun(() => {
    return runScreenshot();
  });
```

Here's the resulting Firebase Functions log. It takes a few seconds to run `puppeteer.launch()`, and then `browser.newPage()` won't finish at all in the 8 minutes it has before the timeout.

```
9:44:04.012 PM
screenshot
Function execution started
9:44:04.555 PM
screenshot
Launching puppeteer...
9:44:09.427 PM
screenshot
launch: 4870.195ms
9:44:09.427 PM
screenshot
Awaiting browser.newPage()...
9:53:04.014 PM
screenshot
Function execution took 540004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

Complete reproducible example: https://github.com/danbockapps/firebase-puppeteer

Comment: Your Cloud Function is declared to run a JS function called `runScreenshot`, but you're showing something called `downloadScreenshot` here.  I suggest editing the question to show the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error, and nothing else.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for catching that. I fixed the question, created a branch with the complete minimal code and added the link at the end.

Comment: You should still show the complete minimal code.  What you have is incomplete.  We should be able to copy exactly what you have and run it for ourselves.  Trim it down to the bare minimum that does not work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson I included the complete code in the question, and linked to my repository which you can clone and run yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `{args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']}` to puppeteer.launch, as recommended here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6568

Answer (score 1):

The function you passed to onRun doesn't return anything.  In that case, it will terminate almost immediately, and little to nothing else will happen.  The asynchronous work is not guaranteed to complete.

What you should do instead is return promise that resovles only after all the async work completes.Since `downloadScreenshot` itself returns a promise, you can just return it:

```
export const screenshot = functions
  .runWith({ memory: '2GB', timeoutSeconds: 540 })
  .pubsub.schedule('27 16 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York')
  .onRun(() => { return downloadScreenshot('tmp/downloaded_image.png') })
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more information.

Comment: This solution is not working. See edited question. It produces the exact same result.